# Very Deep Neural Nets Training Error

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

In theory as we increase the number of layers of neural network the training error must decrease. But Practically it decreases up to a point and increases. Why does this happen?(As mentioned by Andrew Ng in a course)

Answer (score 1):

Because it became a big enough to remember training data and lost its generalization capability.

Comment: Hi @Andrii ,For a big enough network remembering training data should be easy right?

Comment: I think it very depends on NN's architecture, training algorithm and data